How to determine available physical RAM in a RISC-V OS?
I was recently going through the source code for xv6 (https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv), when I came across this line:
(https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/riscv/kernel/memlayout.h)
#define PHYSTOP (KERNBASE + 128*1024*1024)

combine this with the Makefile of the project (https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/riscv/Makefile):
QEMUOPTS = -machine virt -bios none -kernel $K/kernel -m 128M -smp $(CPUS) -nographic

This made me realise that they are just hard coding the OS to assume 128MB of RAM and then specifying the same size to QEMU. However, this is obviously not the case for real operating systems. So, I would like to know how an actual operating system would determine available physical memory?
Upon doing some research, I found online that this information is provided by BIOS of the device. For x86 systems, GNU multiboot.h can provide a lot of this information. In fact this page talks in detail about how to obtain this information. However, this link talks exclusively about the x86 architecture. How can this be achieved in the RISC-V architecture? And how can one test that inside QEMU?

QEMU seems to pass in a device tree in $a1. Actual systems may do the same or use UEFI.

The boot/bios [usually] determines the amount of RAM. Generally, it does this by probing (on a page basis) the RAM until it hits a bus error et. al. Or, some systems put this in the DTB (device tree blob). The DTB is available to the boot and it passes if off to the OS. And/or the boot might use the DTB and probe within the memory ranges it is given

In general - you can't. You have to know the specific machine your OS is supposed to run, you have to know how much RAM does that system have, and you have to provide that info to your OS.
You have to understand, that x86 is in many ways an exceptional architecture. Many lessons you learn with x86 are just not true in general:

x86 has only one popular system architecture - ACPI-compatible PC. Because of that, instruction set architecture (x86) and system architecture (PC) become almost synonyms. This is not true in general - most other ISAs have many different systems built with it.
that "only" x86 system architecture mandates PCI bus (which provides device detection feature) and System Management bus (which provides access to DRAM Serial Presence Detect). That means, that on ACPI PC, both device map and memory map can be discovered at runtime. Many non-PC systems have no memory or device detection at all!
ACPI PC standard also mandates a pretty capable BIOS to be present. Non-PC systems may have only a simple bootloader.

When you program bare metal for non-x86 non-PC system, keep the following in mind:

You don't program for RISC-V, you program for a specific system that has RISC-V as its part. You have to decide which machine/board/SoC your OS would support. Then, get a manual for that machine.
If that machine has BIOS which provides you with device and memory maps - use those.
If it does not - you have to provide target system info to your OS yourself. You either hardcode it in your source code, or you create some kind of "config block" which your OS would read at startup.

